# Rewrite to www AND https for multiple domains not always working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Our platform can be access by multiple domains (one per language/brand). For all domains we force *www.* and *https://*. We do this with one .htaccess file containing following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# FIRST WE REDIRECT TO www. IF NOT ALREADY THE CASE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^firstdomain\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# THEN, WE REDIRECT TO https:// IF NOT ALREADY THE CASE
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.firstdomain\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seconddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It all works fine, **except** for one situation:

When calling directly https://seconddomain.com (without www but with SSL), we get a certificate error (because the domain is not first redirected to www - we only have a certificate for www.*).

The weird thing is, though, that this **problem does not occur with the very first domain** of the list:

https://firstdomain.com -> gets redirected to https://www.firstdomain.com (no error, perfect!)

Why is this only working for the very first domain and not for the subsequent ones?

Thank you for your help!

Summary:

```
WORKS FOR ALL DOMAINS
http://etc -> https://www.etc
http://www.etc -> https://www.etc

WORKS ONLY FOR THE FIRST DOMAIN
https://etc -> https://www.etc
```

Comment: We are using a multi-domain certificate (http://www.geotrust.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-san-uc/). It's issued on "firstdomain.com" though. Might this be the reason why it's only working for firstdomain.com? We have contacted GeoTrust and are awaiting a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, someone from GeoTrust enlightened us on why it isn't working:

We are using a SAN-certificate, issued on www.firstdomain.com. www.seconddomain.com, www.thirddomain.com, etc. are its alternate domains.

As a free bonus, they automatically offer firstdomain.com (without www) in this certificate - only for this main domain though, not the alternate ones.

This is why the redirect from https://firstdomain.com works and not for the others.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^firstdomain\.com [NC,OR]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.firstdomain\.com [NC,OR]
```